# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not use direct buffers with InputStream API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Getting below exception while trying trying to create new dataframe using coalece from an existing dataframe. Despite setting the hadoop config option dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader as true, I am getting the error. The first line runs fine and df is returned but while creating sampleDf, I am getting the error.

Hadoop version - 2.8.5

```
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader", "true");
       
      Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format(format).options(getOptions()).load();
      sampleDf = sparkSession.createDataFrame(df.coalesce(1).limit(rowCount).collectAsList(), df.schema());
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not use direct buffers with InputStream API
        at com.googlesaxcloud.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:209)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.impl.BlockReaderRemote.readNextPacket(BlockReaderRemote.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.impl.BlockReaderRemote.read(BlockReaderRemote.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteArrayStrategy.readFromBlock(ReaderStrategy.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readBuffer(DFSInputStream.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:829)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:456)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:456)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:486)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Tried setting this hadoop config flag as true/false but still got the same error.
Blockreader flag reference - https://docs.rapidminer.com/9.7/radoop/troubleshooting/known-errors.html

Comment: Please summarize the error; you do not need to put the whole traceback here. Just put the error message to make your questoine more clear.